# Include JS-created text in RSS feed

Tags: javascript, xml, rss, jekyll

I am generating a weekly e-newsletter from blog posts via an RSS feed. There's a weekly birthday list that I generate with a javascript array. The text shows up just fine for the post, but it's ignored in the feed. Likewise if I try to bring it in via a Jekyll/Liquid include.

Is there any way to remedy this, or will xml only read the html generated outside of javascript?

**Edit**:    [Here's a CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OxqyBo) with the relevant html and javascript. You can see it's pretty straightforward Jekyll blogging with yaml front material. The javascript reads from an array, compares it to the publication date, and returns a list of people with birthdays in the coming week.

So here's the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <channel>
        <title>{{ site.title | xml_escape }}</title>
        <description>{{ site.description | xml_escape }}</description>
        <link>{{ site.url }}{{ site.baseurl }}/</link>
        <atom:link href="http://stpaulsmalone.org/feed.xml" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml"/>
        <pubDate>{{ site.time | date_to_rfc822 }}</pubDate>
        <lastBuildDate>{{ site.time | date_to_rfc822 }}</lastBuildDate>
        <generator>Jekyll v{{ jekyll.version }}</generator>
        {% for post in site.posts limit:10 %}
        {% if post.categories contains 'news' %}
          <item>
            <title>{{ post.title | xml_escape }}</title>
            <description>
                {{ post.teaser | xml_escape }}
                <![CDATA[ <img src="http://stpaulsmalone.org/img/news/{{ post.img }}"> ]]>
                {{ post.content | xml_escape }}
            </description>
            <pubDate>{{ post.date | date_to_rfc822 }}</pubDate>
            <link>{{ post.url | prepend: site.baseurl | prepend: site.url }}</link>
            <guid isPermaLink="true">{{ post.url | prepend: site.baseurl | prepend: site.url }}</guid>
            {% for tag in post.tags %}
            <category>{{ tag | xml_escape }}</category>
            {% endfor %}
            {% for cat in post.categories %}
            <category>{{ cat | xml_escape }}</category>
            {% endfor %}
          </item>
        {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
      </channel>
</rss>
```

Building the xml file using Liquid variables works just fine. Anything that can be put in the front material can be distributed via the RSS feed. What the feed *won't* do is pick up the birthday list, or anything generated via a Liquid include. So the question is: is there a way to get it to do that, or am I just stuck?

Comment: Very confusing what you are asking since rss is xml which is not a programming language. Need a much better description of the problem, particularly what javascript has to do with this. Also provide relevant code as per [mcve]

Comment: Let's see if I can make this clearer:
*html I generate in the post flows through RSS feed just fine
*html generated through javascript is ignored in the RSS feed.

Comment: generated where and with what code and how is it passed to the rss xml? Not clear at all without a properly detailed explanation

Comment: Hand-written html picked up with a feed.xml file, created with the assistance of some Liquid variables.

Comment: That is simply too vague. You have not offered nearly enough detail or code for anyone to help troubleshoot your issue

Comment: All right, my apologies. I've added a CodePen and some more information above.